# dynamic addeventlistener onclick return only last result from array

Tags: php, jquery

I had a dynamic `document.createElement` in my code. I want to add `addEventListener - onclick` to all `<div>` created. The problem I faced is all the onclick event returned last result from my array.

```
var table = [
                [ "H", "Hydrogen", "1.00794", 1, 1 ],
                [ "He", "Helium", "4.002602", 18, 1 ],
                [ "Li", "Lithium", "6.941", 1, 2 ],
                [ "Be", "Beryllium", "9.012182", 2, 2 ],
            ]; 

for ( var i = 0; i < table.length; i ++ ) {

        var item = table[ i ];


        var element = document.createElement( 'div' );
        element.setAttribute("id", "element_"+i);
        element.className = 'element';
        element.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,127,127,' + ( Math.random() * 0.5 + 0.25 ) + ')';
        element.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        element.addEventListener("click", function(e){ alert(item[0]); });
}
```

when I clicked on any div it only alert me "Be", which is the last result in my array. How should I add the event handler to each specific `<div>`. I had try with `bind` but then the alert box wont shown when I clicked and it does not show any error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of wrong usage of closure variable `item`

```
var table = [
    [ "H", "Hydrogen", "1.00794", 1, 1 ],
    [ "He", "Helium", "4.002602", 18, 1 ],
    [ "Li", "Lithium", "6.941", 1, 2 ],
    [ "Be", "Beryllium", "9.012182", 2, 2 ]
]; 

for ( var i = 0; i < table.length; i ++ ) {
    (function(idx){
        var item = table[ idx ];
        var element = document.createElement( 'div' );
        element.setAttribute("id", "element_"+idx);
        element.className = 'element';
        element.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,127,127,' + ( Math.random() * 0.5 + 0.25 ) + ')';
        element.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        element.addEventListener("click", function(e){ 
            alert(item); 
        });
    })(i)

}
```

In this case the event callback is trying to access the closure variable `item`, but the value of `item` is not evaluated until the click event is executed, by that time the value of item is changed.

Comment: you helped me again. Thanks. =)